# Named pipe details

Tags: c#, c++, pipe, named-pipes

I need to send messages from a C#.Net application to a C++ application on Windows. They'll be running on the same PC. After doing some research, it sounds like using a named pipe might work. But I'm still confused about several details. So if anyone can fill me in, I'd appreciate it.

1. It sounds like a named pipe is basically a type of file. If my .Net application keeps writing to the file, will it keep getting larger? Or will whatever I'm writing go away as soon as the C++ application has read it?
2. If I send a message with a single write() call, am I guaranteed that it will be read together, or could it be broken up? For example, if I send "hello", is it possible the timing will be such that I'll read "hel" and then "lo"?
3. Am I correct that if I send several messages before trying to read them, they just sit there and I can read several at once? Will it take multiple read() calls to get every message, or will they all come concatenated together?
4. Is there any way for the C++ application to know that a message is waiting? Or should I just have a loop going that tries to read a message, sleeps, then tries to read again?

Answer (score 1):

> It sounds like a named pipe is basically a type of file. If my .Net application keeps writing to the file, will it keep getting larger? Or will whatever I'm writing go away as soon as the C++ application has read it?

A pipe doesn't really have a size. There may be some number of bytes in it, and you could call that the size of the pipe. This would be cosmetic. Why do you care? If your concern is that pipes may be implemented terribly on your platform, then you should switch platforms.

> If I send a message with a single write() call, am I guaranteed that it will be read together, or could it be broken up? For example, if I send "hello", is it possible the timing will be such that I'll read "hel" and then "lo"?

Pipes are streams of bytes. There is no such thing as a message on a pipe. (At least, as far as the pipe knows.)

> Am I correct that if I send several messages before trying to read them, they just sit there and I can read several at once? Will it take multiple read() calls to get every message, or will they all come concatenated together?

There aren't messages. Pipes are streams of bytes. If you try to read 100 bytes, you will get 100 bytes, unless there are fewer than that number available.

> Is there any way for the C++ application to know that a message is waiting? Or should I just have a loop going that tries to read a message, sleeps, then tries to read again?

You can have a thread block on reading the pipe. That thread can exist just to permit a simple way for you to query whether a message is waiting, for example, by feeding bytes read from the pipe into a thread-safe queue of some kind. It could include the application-level message protocol logic, so the queue would consist of complete application-level messages.

A pipe pretty much acts like a TCP connection as far as the read and write semantics go.

Comment: You need to tweak to cover message-type pipes, PipeTransmissionMode.Message in a C# program.  And overlapped I/O on the C++ side.